# How do I change stylesheet using a dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following uses buttons to swap between stylesheets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<script>
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Javascript Change StyleSheet Without Page Reload</h2>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('dark.css')">Dark Style Sheet</button>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('blue.css')">Blue Style Sheet</button>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('default.css')">Default Style Sheet</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to use the same function but instead of using buttons, be able to swap by selecting stylesheets from a dropdown box. I have set one up like this, using links:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="swapStyleSheet('default.css')">Default</a>
                    <a href="swapStyleSheet('dark.css')">Dark</a>
               </div>
```

When loaded in the browser, clicking these links takes me to "page cannot be found". I assume i have written the links in the wrong format, what can i do to fix them? Thanks!

If anything in this question is unclear, please let me know before down voting. I am new to SO and i want to get it right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onclick` event as following

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" onclick="swapStyleSheet('default.css')">Default</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="swapStyleSheet('dark.css')">Dark</a>
           </div>
```

I advise you to use a library like [jQuery](https://jquery.com) or something else.